# Minimum distance between two curves / Minimum Pixel count between two curves

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have converted it into binary and tried to find the contours with help of canny contours. I would like to ask how can I find the minimumm distance between two curves(as shown in figure) to find the diameter of the bridge.

Answer (score 4):

Sum the columns of pixels with:

```
columnSums = np.sum(image, axis=0)
```

All the columns that sum to zero are fully black, so count the ones that are adjacent and sum to zero.

I have totalled up the columns and added a summation at the bottom of the image below so you can see what I mean:

[image]